# Running ruby sript with Cron in Centos7 Docker image

Tags: cron, docker, centos

I've setup a cron job in my centos7 docker image but its not working

```
crontab -e
    >> * * * * * ruby myrubyfile.rb
```

This same cron job is working on my actual centos7 machine.

Comment: What is your output of the container? How does your Dockerfile look? Is the image including all dependencies required to run cron and ruby? Is the cron deamon running? Have you tried docker exec -i -t yourContainerName /bin/bash to enter your running container and to debug it?

Comment: @ReneM. I'm starting the container with `docker run -it -p 3030:3030 myimage bash` then setting up the cron job and waiting to see if it executes. I've got cronie and ruby installed. Not sure about cron daemon, how to i check that?

Comment: Yeah, the cron daemon won't be running by default in a container. You'll need to set up something to start it, or come up with a different solution.

Comment: OK then you know now how to do it. But I would setup a correct dockerfile, which is installing and setting up all correctly and accepting all configuration parameters as environ vars. That's the way it's done

Comment: possible duplicate of [Docker CentOS 7 - cron not working in local machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644391/docker-centos-7-cron-not-working-in-local-machine)

Comment: I added a duplicate flag on your question, because I found one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644391/docker-centos-7-cron-not-working-in-local-machine first match on google when searching why no crond on centos docker image. Because systemd is disabled in centos docker image

Comment: @ReneM. I'm aware of that but the solution on that question didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cron was working all along, however when running inside the container i needed to have the full path to ruby. The following worked:

```
* * * * * /root/.rbenv/shims/ruby /myrubyfile.rb
```